# UITableViewController is not updating content is I apply manual sorting

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, sorting, nsindexpath

using a UITableViewController, where I am displaying some products which are sorted based on make year. Whenever user taps in a row (each row represents a single product) a new view gets displayed to edit the same product.

So after save if the user has changed the make year then it should display in main table view at appropriate place (i.e. sorted again accordingly).
To accomplish this I am calling sort() method in.... here sort method returns NSMutableArray type of object.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Sort the records based on number of days.
    sortedProducts = [DTOConverter sort:unsortedProducts];

    return [sortedProducts count];
}
```

But the problem is that in table view I am still having the old values in that particular row until I bounce the entire view then it gets populated with new updated values.

Same thing happens in case of a new product gets added.
Please correct me where I am doing wrong, I am sure that the issue might be related to indexPath, but i do not know how to tackle it. Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update tableview data call

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: by putting reloadData in my numberOfRowsInSection method this method is getting called continuously and at the end app crashes.

Comment: It is not supposed to be in there.no of rows is a function asking for no of rows sorting and other thing should be done outside and it will be called after sort

Comment: noOfRows in section should be used only to return the row count

Comment: do it like this .after you get all data sort it and store it in array.then call this reloadData.

Comment: this reloadData invokes all datasource methods once again and populate tablevie hence form the loop and cause crash

Comment: i did the way you mentioned, which is gett all the data, sort it and then storing it in some array ,and right after i am calling [tableView reloadData], and it is working as expected. But the only glitch is I am getting little lag while returning to main view where I am displaying this sorted list. Any improvement on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the table or the individual row with one of the following methods:

- reloadData
- reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation
- reloadSections:withRowAnimation
- reloadSectionIndexTitles

See the documentation on each method: [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView)

Note: if you are only updating one row, do not call [tableView reloadData]. It is not necessary to reload all of the data in the table.

Comment: realodData is crashing my app. Tried with reloadRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation but having same issue - 'code' (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Sort the records based on number of days.
    sortedProducts = [DTOConverter sort:unsortedProducts];
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.sortedProducts count] - 1 inSection:0];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    
    return [sortedProducts count];
} 'code'

Comment: Where are you calling reloadData from?

Comment: In method -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView )tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: I believe this method will only be called when the table is reloaded. So by putting reloadData in this method, you are creating a loop. Please see the other answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set up a delegate in the new view you are loading from your tableview and then set up your tableviewcontroller to implement the delegate method of that new viewcontroller. Then call reload data from that delegate method Here is an example of a delegate: [Delegate example](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/)